# Creating a self signed certificate with CSR using openssl

Tags: openssl, x509certificate, x509, self-signed, csr

Edit (to stress on openssl):

I have a CSR and I am trying to self sign the csr with openssl.
The result is that the csr is not matching the certificate.

Here are the openssl commands I used:

- Generate a new private key:
  genrsa -des3 -out private.pem 2048
- Convert the csr from der to pem format:
  x509 -in okta_csr.der -inform DER -out okta_csr.pem -outform PEM -req
- self sign the certificate:
  x509 -in okta_csr.pem -out okta_cert.pem -signkey private.pem -days 100

I have used https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html to verify whether CSR (okta_csr.der) and certificate (okta_cert.pem) match and the result is that they don't.

What am I doing wrong that the csr and cert are not matching?